# Linux Mint date/time settings

Tags: linux-mint

So I noticed that Linux Mint listed the date and time in the lower right corner at the bottom of the screen in the 24-hour clock format. Following the link I tried setting the *date format in the panel* as follows: %A, %b %d. But now it doesn't show the time!

So what is the format to display the date *and* the time in 12 hour format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: %a %b %e, %I:%M %p  the result should be the default configuration with the  12 hours clock format .